# How to get id of a certain row from DB through input?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I use php to show as many inputs as many values are in table.

```
<?php foreach($videos as $videos_item): ?>
    <div class="row video-input">
        <input type="text" name="videos_inputs[]" 
           value="<?php echo 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $videos_item['video_url']; ?>" 
           placeholder="Ссылка на видео" class="form__input">
        <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>/admin/delete_video.php?id=<?php echo $videos['id']; ?>" 
           class="form_video__delete">Удалить</a>
    </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

But I also need to get ID of each row.

```
foreach ($videos_inputs as $val) {
    $value = $val;

    $add_videos = $db->prepare(
        'UPDATE videos SET 
            video_url = :video_url 
            WHERE id = :id'
    );

    $add_videos->execute([
        'video_url' => $value,
        'id' => $video_id
    ]);
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Change your form to this:

```
<?php foreach($videos as $videos_item): ?>
    <div class="row video-input">
        <input type="text" name="videos_inputs[<?php echo $videos['id'];?>]" 
           value="<?php echo 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $videos_item['video_url']; ?>" 
           placeholder="Ссылка на видео" class="form__input">
        <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>/admin/delete_video.php?id=<?php echo $videos['id']; ?>" 
           class="form_video__delete">Удалить</a>
    </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

And you php code for updates to this:

```
foreach ($videos_inputs as $video_id => $val) {
    $value = $val;

    $add_videos = $db->prepare(
        'UPDATE videos SET 
            video_url = :video_url 
            WHERE id = :id'
    );

    $add_videos->execute([
        'video_url' => $value,
        'id' => $video_id
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below example in your code...

```
SET @update_id := 0;
UPDATE some_table SET column_name = 'value', id = (SELECT @update_id := id)
WHERE some_other_column = 'blah' LIMIT 1; 
SELECT @update_id;
```

Note : this will return updated row id.

Hope this will work for you.